# oAuth Token in Laravel 5.5

Tags: api, postman, laravel-5.5

I am trying to develop an API using Laravel5.5. In this regard I am using POSTMAN. My end point is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token`. But I am getting output `Not allowed.`.

[image]

Comment: Did you install Laravel Passport?

Comment: Thanks @umuttaymaz.  Yes, I installed Laravel Passport. Thanks.